# How to get fixed table columns width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

How do you make individual table columns fixed for a certain width so no matter how much text is in that column, the width of the column stays the same?

`<col>` tag is only good for firefox

`table-layout:fixed` is for whole table really

Just setting a `width` does not do it

what is the best css property to use for this

Below is code:

```
    .video{
        overflow:hidden;
        table-layout:fixed;
        max-width:146px;
                }
            .audio{
        overflow:hidden;
        table-layout:fixed;
        max-width:146px;
                }
            .image{
        overflow:hidden;
        table-layout:fixed;
        max-width:146px;
                }
             .qid2{
        overflow:hidden;
        table-layout:fixed;
        max-width:92px;
                }

  <table border=1 id="vidtbl">
    <tr>
    <th>Question No</th>
    <th>Video</th>
    <th>Audio</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="qid2"></td>
    <td class="video">images/dolphinvideo.png//////////////////////////////////////</td>
    <td class="audio">hello</td>
    <td class="image"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting width in td tag?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try using

```
max-width:100px;
```

or

```
max-height:100px;
```

This will let your column expand maximum upto the width you set.

Comment: That didn't work but thank you for this answer because I never known bout max-width b4. I included this on css and put it on my question so you have better idea of my css for a table column

Comment: put a DIV inside your TD and make the widht of TD fixed upto some percentage.. and then Try using this style to TD .. ` {
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: got it working, needed to include min-width, because of you informing me of max-width which i havn't heard about which also got me aware of min-width, u deserve to get best answer, thanks :)

Comment: @Malcolm, additional note: max-height and width is not supported in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: @all, Please mention the reason for down-voting the answer. so everyone can be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the contents of the <td> in another tag with width and overflow:hidden. For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fifty">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </td>
  </td>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.fifty p { overflow:hidden; width:50px; }
```

Comment: Remember that tables should be used exclusively for tabular data and should not be used for page layout. Google "tableless layout" for a number of examples of why tables aren't suited for page layout and what alternatives are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use width attribute in td tag

```
<td width="100px">
```

or you can use style attribute

```
<td style="width:100px">
```

or you can define it in css file

```
.tdstyle{
    width:100px;
}
```

and specify the class in td tag

```
<td class="tdstyle">
```

Comment: No no no, I know how to use css, my problem is that if I just set a width attribute, if I have a large piece of text in a 120px column in a table with other columns which are 120px, then the column with the text goes wider and the other columns shrink. I don't want that, I want all columns to be 120px and no more or less

Comment: no but height can vary, its just width as table is shown on pop up window 550px by 550px

Comment: setting width attribute it <td> tag is working fine for me. Its not overlapping the other column. Instead, the height of the column is increased. Im not sure why its not working for you. Which browser are you using. ? What do you mean by '550px by 550px'. What are these 2 values?

Answer (score 0):

If setting td's width to a fix value does not work for you:

```
<td width="100">..</td> or <td style="width:100px">...</td>
```

Wrapped the content to a div and set the overflow as hidden:

```
<td><div style="width:100px;overflow:hidden;">...</div></td>
```

Css class will be much efficient and easy to maintain though:

```
.col120 { width:120px; overflow:hidden;}

<td><div class="col120">content...</div></td>
```

Comment: yep still not working, does table need to be set a width also

Comment: wats happening is that if I fill in text then the column goes up to max width, when there is no text then column shrinks, I think I know what I need to do, give me 2 mins, I might need to set min-width

Comment: can you post the resulting html?

Comment: you must wrap the content with <div> and apply the class on the div not on the td

Comment: .video{width:120px;overflow:hidden;} <td><div  class="video">images/dolphinvideo.png//////////////////////////////////////</div></td>